# rendering SLS 'base:test.test1' failed: Jinja variable 'list object' has no attribute 'sub1'

Tags: salt-stack

My SLS file is as below and When trying to access the variable **tst1** i get an error, details are as follows

```
{% load_yaml as test %}
    value:
      val1: 'string1'
      val2: 'string2'
    value1: ['sub1','sub2']
{% endload %}

{%- for tst in test.value1 -%}

{% set tst1 = test.value1[tst] %}

{{ tst1 }}

{%- endfor -%}
```

When trying to access the variable **tst1** i get the below error as below.

```
rendering SLS 'base:test.test1' failed: Jinja variable 'list object' has no attribute 'sub1'
```

Can anyone help on what exactly the error pointing to ?

Comment: Once you get the `tst1` variable by iterating, what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

> `{% set tst1 = test.value1[tst] %}`

In this line you are trying to access a dict. `test.value1` is a list, not a dict.
I think this is exactly what you want:

**Code**

```
{%- for tst in test.value1 -%}

{{ tst }}

{%- endfor -%}
```

**Output**

```
sub1sub2
```

Comment: Thanks @SynPrime. I tried above but did not work... get an error as 

```
rendering SLS 'base:test.test1' failed: Could not find expected ':'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the SLS file should contain IDs (tasks) that are to be executed with modules. Like:

```yaml
do-something:
  module.name:
    - args
    ...
```

Just putting something like `{{ tst }}` will not work as it expects a mapping like `do-something:`

So in the `for` loop, you should "invoke" some module. I'm using `test.echo` to show the values in the below example:

```yaml
{% for tst in test.value1 %}
show-value1-{{ tst }}:
  module.run:
    - name: test.echo
    - text: '{{ tst }}'
{% endfor %}
```